# How can we understand the $g$-factor as a property of the wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation, magnetic-moment

I saw some fancy derivation of the fact that $g = 2$ in the Dirac equation, but I couldn't really follow it.  And I imagine it's about 100 times harder in QED.  What I really want is to understand what the gyromagnetic ratio or $g$-factor (not quite clear on the difference...) tells us about the behavior of the wavefunction (or path integral thereof).  For example, what we thought of classically as the mass, turns out to be the frequency of oscillation of the free field; now that's a fascinating insight!  So, what about $g$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The angular momentum about an axis tells you how the phase of the wavefunction changes if you rotate it about that axis. The magnetic moment vector tells you how much energy the particle will have if you put the particle in a magnetic field of known strength and direction (and, as you were getting at, the energy in turn tells you how the phase of the wavefunction changes in time). There is a relationship between the charge, angular momentum, and magnetic moment of a spinning particle that you can derive in classical electromagnetism. The gyromagnetic ratio tells you how to correct that relationship so that it holds in quantum mechanics, for that particle.

Incidentally, the derivation that $g\approx 2$ in QED is the same one that you are referring to using the Dirac equation; I strongly recommend going through this derivation carefully, and you could always ask one or more questions here to clarify any confusion you have going through it. However, there are higher order terms so $g$ is not exactly $2$; in fact, $g=2\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{2\pi} + \cdots\right)$, where $\alpha$ is the fine-structure constant. The difficult part, that you need the machinery of QED for, is computing the correction terms, like $\alpha/2\pi$.